# Timeout for firestore operations

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to set timeout for `firestore` operations like read, write and update?. Because  When connection is not there.. it's not triggering `OnCompleteListener`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no configurable timeouts for Firestore reads and writes.  The Firestore SDK will automatically retry database operations with the assumption that connectivity will return shortly.

If you want to force some code to run after some amount of time has elapsed, you will have to implement your own timer.

If you want to only use locally cached values rather than require a round trip with the server, you can specify a source of "cache" in the query as well.  For example, in Android, use [get(Source)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#get(com.google.firebase.firestore.Source)) instead of the normal get().

Comment: How long does a `server` source query wait before timing out and using the local cache instead? Is there really no way to control this value? It seems like this is possible in some SDKs, for example in .NET: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/2471

Comment: It's something like 500ms.  It's not controllable by any documented means.  And it's not really a timeout.  The server query will augment the original cache results whenever it's done.

Comment: @DougStevenson when the app goes offline, do cached writes have a shelf life in the client? Or do they persist practically "forever" until a connection is reestablished?

Answer (score 2):

Firestore Get method have a parameter to define timeout (float):

```
.get(timeout=500000)
```

[Here is API documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/collection.html)