# Python script freezes trying to connect to Firestore Database

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple script to get some data from Google Firestore Database.
In most cases the script runs fine however sometimes it just freezes giving a timeout error after a while. I wonder what may cause this issue and how can I troubleshoot/debug this?

Script code:

```py
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import firestore

app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()

db = firestore.client()

def get_name(room: str) -> str:
    '''Returns the name of given room resident'''
    room_ref = db.collection('users').document(room)
    name = room_ref.get().to_dict()['residentName']
    return name

print(get_name('A101'))
```

Error message on timeout:

```py
raise exceptions.RetryError(
google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Deadline of 300.0s exceeded while calling target function, last exception: 504 Deadline Exceeded
```

I checked the documentation but I couldn't find any specific limitations for this simple project.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to format code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Have you tried using the parameter **timeout** in your **get** method? Maybe increasing your deadline solves the timeout error. See [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/collection) and this related SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947496/timeout-for-firestore-operations#:~:text=There%20are%20no%20configurable%20timeouts,to%20implement%20your%20own%20timer.).

Comment: Ever figure this out? Seeing the same thing

Comment: Hi @MScottWaller unfortunately I did not find a solution to this problem. Please post your answer if you were able to figure this out.